# Heroku ruby rails 4 with heroku ExecJS::ProgramError: Unexpected token: error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment, sqlite

Hey guys im trying to deploy my ruby on rails 4 app on Heroku but having a problem on execution. Im using sqlite3 and I have tried everything.

This is the error on the last stage:

remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
    remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
    remote:        rake aborted!
    remote:        ExecJS::ProgramError: Unexpected token: operator (<<) (line: 16, col: 0, pos: 391)
    remote:        Error
    remote:        at new JS_Parse_Error (/tmp/execjs20150126-932-1636928js:2359:10623)
    remote:        at js_error (/tmp/execjs20150126-932-1636928js:2359:10842)
    remote:        at croak (/tmp/execjs20150126-932-1636928js:2359:19086)
    remote:        at token_error (/tmp/execjs20150126-932-1636928js:2359:19223)
    remote:        at unexpected (/tmp/execjs20150126-932-1636928js:2359:19311)
    remote:        at expr_atom (/tmp/execjs20150126-932-1636928js:2359:27526)
    remote:        at maybe_unary (/tmp/execjs20150126-932-1636928js:2359:30019)
    remote:        at expr_ops (/tmp/execjs20150126-932-1636928js:2359:30777)
    remote:        at maybe_conditional (/tmp/execjs20150126-932-1636928js:2359:30869)
    remote:        at maybe_assign (/tmp/execjs20150126-932-1636928js:2359:31312)
    remote:        (in /tmp/build_c9b90b740808f1b53c01e698e6740e18/app/assets/javascripts/app.js.orig)/tmp/build_c9b90b740808f1b53c01e698e6740e18/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/execjs-2.2.2/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:64:in `extract_result'
    remote:        /tmp/build_c9b90b740808f1b53c01e698e6740e18/vendor/bundle

my application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require jquery-ui
```

gemfile:

```
group :development do
gem 'sqlite3'
end
group :production do
gem 'pg'
gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

at the moment when I run this command:

```
 bundle exec rake --trace assets:precompile
```

I get:

```
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute assets:precompile
```

But before I got something different which told me to go into public/assets/(a really long ass file name).js right next to the execution assets:precompile. When I went into the file, it did have a few "<<". It was generated by foundation I think but I dont wanna touch anything.

Comment: Why don' you try to disable all of your js and deploy it, see what's going to happne.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing this issue as well. I found that multiline comments can cause this issue as well.

```
<!-- -->
```

This is a wrong syntax for multiline comments in js hence all the trouble.

These should be replaced with // comments

This fixed the issue for me.

And in order to find the issue, I had to run assets precompile task locally with development first, sprockets did not try to compress the file and it went through, then I could go to the line number to find the comment that was causing all the trouble.